# Excel: Data Analyzing and Drop Down Options

Tags: excel

Trying to create an excel spreadsheet which will allow me to select an option at the top of the page (a dropdown) which will be a list of names. I then want a grid below to be able to show (as an example) an individuals results over a month. This is a preference as I didn't want to have to go through multiple pages to view individual information and rather see it all in one location.

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a data validation linked to the range of student names on another sheet and then an INDEX, MATCH or VLOOKUP formulas to populate the table from the other sheets..